# UWP package creation Error info: Packaname different

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-store-apps, appxmanifest, makeappx

I have an issue updating my UWP app on Windows store. The issue is on the level of Visual studio (for windows). The description of the issue is the following:

Error info: error 80080204: The package with file name "MyApp_VersionNumber_x64.msix" and package full name "PackageName_VersionNumber_x64__Suffix" is not valid in the bundle because it has a different package family name than other packages in the bundle. The expected publisher is CN=PublisherName.    AppName Prefix_Path\AppName\MakeAppx

The context is the following:

1. I update the app source code, then I associated the app in the store with the one updated.
2. In the windows related to the Application packages creation:
   a. I choosed the distribute the application in windows store
   b. Next, I choosed to always generate the application bath. (When I choose not to generate, it is impossible to publish the update because appxbundle is missing)
   c. I selected the build x86, x64 and ARM like I did before
   d. Finally I launch the creation to get the error above.

I followed multiple possible answer but nothing works.
Can someone helps me to overcome this issue?

Regards.

Comment: The error message mentioned the package family name is not matched. Please check it in the manifest file and compare it with the package family name in the Partner Center.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/f0192ada-cc54-417a-a984-5135ed3cf10e/uwp-urgent-create-app-packages-bundleartifactsuploadx86txt-not-found?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Thank you for the additionnal answer. I should be able to test it soon. I will let you know if it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the fix is a bit annoying, but for me it worked:

Close Visual Studio, go into your fileexplorer and open up the Folder with your project. Inside it you should find the "projectname.csproj" file. Open it up in your favorite texteditor and now follow the steps below:

**1: Look for this line and also make sure it is the line with 'Release' and not 'Debug' in it:**

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
```

**2: Inside the PropertyGroup tags you will find this line:**
The value can either be true or false. If it is false, change it to true

```
<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
```

Now repeate these steps for all four Release configurations and **ONLY** Release not Debug:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM64'">
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
```

After this, save the file and reopen Visual Studio. It now should create the package.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The issue using the Native tool chain is that the obfuscation tool I used "Babel" make the compilation freezes and the application packages are never created. However I will try you solution and let you know if it works. Thank you.